Re-Use .NET Core Web Application Project for multiple applications
I have the following:

ASP .NET Core Web Application Project containing Quartz.NET Scheduler
Application Project A for Customer A with Services and Quartz.NET Jobs etc.
Application Project B for Customer B with Services and Quartz.NET Jobs etc.

The .NET Core Web Application Project is used to have a GUI for editing the Jobs, viewing logs, applying database migrations etc.
The Application Projects (A and B) contain unrelated functionality but both should be able to use the Scheduler and the Web Application to edit the jobs etc.
Is there a possibility to modify the Web Application project that way, that I can have the code only once and then "use" it from both application projects. Something like:
builder.Services.AddMyWebApplication();
...
app.UseMyWebApplication();

Or that I have the Web Application Project once and add the Application projects like plugins (without having to reference both of them beforehand)?

where is the problem in referencing the core-project in A and B?

My advice would be to loosely bind them so e.g. ServiceA have an http endpoint you can point to. Else I don't really see how you reverse the quartz code I assume you have that looks like: scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)

In my opinion, you should develop the core application as a web API or directly a class library , then the Application Project A for Customer A  and Application Project B for Customer B , GUI application could call that web api or that class library to achieve your requirement.

Here's what I understand you have at the moment, in terms of dependencies (apologies for the rudimentary diagrams, the arrows show dependencies - e.g. Project A "depends" on both the core app and Quartz.Net).
In the core app you have a UI and logic - I'm assuming that the "plug-in" apps (A & B) only integrate at the logic layer of the core app.  If this is not the case, please advise.

Regarding your question:

Is there a possibility to modify the Web Application project that way,
that I can have the code only once and then "use" it from both
application projects

...and...

Or that I have the Web Application Project once and add the
Application projects like plugins (without having to reference both of
them beforehand)?

Yes.  This is broadly what I think you need - let me give you a diagram and some explanation:

I assume the core app has it's internal logic arranged in layers (if not you should think about moving in that direction over time).  Put all your core logic into a layer that can then be reused by both the UI and the "plug-in" projects.
Ideally this core logic layer should not have any dependencies on "externals" like database technologies or Quartz.Net - the Scheduling Interface I have included is short-hand for some sort of code-level interface/contract/dependency-injection mechanism so that your core logic is not bound to Quartz.Net.  You haven't specifically asked for that in your question but its something you may want to consider doing.
The part that is necessary is to avoid having the plug-in projects bound to both your core logic and Quartz.Net because one day that is likely to bite you.  When plugging-in Projects A or B (or C, D, ... Z) it'll be easier if they only have to integrate with interfaces you control.  All the Quartz.Net logic you need to write you can write once, and not write/duplicate as much of it in the plug-in projects.
Side note: If you are aware of the Ports & Adaptors architectural style (aka Hexagonal) the 'conversation' with Quartz.Net would be a port/adaptor.  This same approach is also used in the Clean architectural style.
The other part of your question was about exactly how to integrate the plug-in projects.  The A/B Interface on my diagram is shorthand for this.
You would design one or several code-level API's (public methods on your core logic classes) that are expressly designed for the plug-in projects to consume.  I have no ideas exactly what your application does - you may have one API or several, see: Interface segregation principle.
This would allow you to do this, using separate solutions:

Core solution: has only the projects needed to develop and test the core app.  Explicitly does not include project A or B code.  Can include mock/test-harness code for testing the A/B Interface(s).
Project A solution: uses the "output" of the core solution. The only "development" is on the Project A specific logic/parts.
Project B solution: rinse and repeat of the project A solution, but for project B.

Depending on your situation, this architecture will allow you to develop plug-in applications that can then be independently deployed and run side-by-side, so development and deployment of plug-in projects, and the core app, is completely de-coupled.

Adiran, thank you very much for your detailed answer! Please give me some time to digest, I'll get back to you.
